# Responsive full width input with button

Tags: html, css

I have the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ufLpqdtj/

My problem is trying to get my search box and button to always sit full width on the page regardless of the device it is running on.

In Javascript I could always make the text box width 100% minus the pixel width of the button (the button is always the same size) but I feel as if im missing something and that it can be done natively in CSS.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

```css
#commonSearchContainer {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#commonSearchTerm {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  height: 35px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.common-search-term-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.common-search-button {
  background-color: #E9700D;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px 0px 0px 10px;
  width: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px;
  font-style: italic;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchSection" class="common-search-section">
  <div class="common-search-term-wrapper">
    <input id="commonSearchTerm" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="common-search-term">
  </div>
  <div id="commonSearchSubmit" class="common-search-button">
    Search
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I typically do for that sort of layout is make a parent container around the elements (like you have) and give it `position: relative` and `width: 100%`.

Then I use `position: absolute` and `display: inline-block` on the inner elements. Set the width for the fixed-sized elements and use `left` or `right` to position all of the elements.

In your case, it would be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ufLpqdtj/1/

Comment: Perfect. Nailed it on the head. I was close, just had a few things off. Thanks for the working example too.

Answer (score 2):

Well you shouldn't use the div as a button. There are html elements for that.

If correctly understood what you want to achieve...

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  }

#commonSearchTerm {
  width: 80%;
}
#searchButton {
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  padding: 2px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form >
  <input id="commonSearchTerm" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="common-search-term">
  <input id="searchButton" type="submit">
</form>
```

This is using flexbox which is is more flexible when creating responsive stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your answer even though it was different for what I was requesting. Inline flex is only supported in CSS3 so not suitable, also the div button is because it is the baseline for a button that will have an image inside as well as text, and also a drop down option inside it.

Comment: @Nick well nobody stops you from adding image to the button and attaching drop down to it and in the end it would look cleaner. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it took the information and provided the minor changes to complete what I needed instead of rebuilding the entire solution. The current code is the prototype to what is going to be a much more complex button that exceeds what the traditional submit button can provide. You will find it is a very common practice to build your own controls to meet different requirements. Thank you for your solution though! What doesn't help me may be exactly what someone else needs!